# Understanding argument prescan process of preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I am trying to understand argument prescan process. [GCC argument prescan documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html), says that,

`Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body`, and also it provides a simple example about the prescan process. To understand this process correctly, I wrote a simple program using this simple example to demonstrate the behaviour of preprocessor.

```
#define foo a,b
#define bar(x) lose(x)
#define lose(x) (1 + (x))

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int c = bar(foo);
}
```

When I run preprocessor with -E switch, I got the following error:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:11:20: error: macro "lose" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
   11 |     int c = bar(foo);
```

But, From the documentation, I understand that, first macro arguments are expanded.
Therefore, My expectation is; after the first scan, **bar(foo)** should be converted to **bar(a,b)**, and because bar expects just one argument, preprocessor should give an error something like:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:11:20: error: macro "bar" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
   11 |     int c = bar(foo);
```

So, clearly, my understanding is wrong but I don't know how to interpret the related gcc document correctly ?

Can you help me about that issue ? Can you list the operations that are performed from preprocessor step by step ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In `bar(foo)`, `bar` has one argument. That argument, `foo`, is macro-replaced and becomes `a,b`. That is still one argument, with a comma in it. It is not reparsed to become two arguments.

Then `bar(foo)` is replaced by `lose(x)`, where `x` is `a,b`, so it becomes `lose(a,b)`. This is parsed to find the arguments of `lose`. There are two arguments, `a` and `b`, but `lose` is defined to take only one, so the compiler complains.